# Async with useEffect and loading data into variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I am trying to use `mainData` which is an object, that is populated by Supabase via a join. Using `segment:SignalJourneyAudiences(segment) ,`

Which will give me:

```js
segment: {segment: xyz}
```

I have this new array which is using that object which is returned from the join like the below.

```js
const unquieConstraints = [
    ...new Map(
      mainData
        .filter(row => row.segment.segment === segment.segment.segment)
        .map(item => [item.constraint_value, item]),
    ).values(),
  ]
```

But as Supabase runs async functions, and I am running it in `useEffect` I get that it can't be read. You can see below that it loads empty then after `useEffect` has called the async function it loads the `mainData`

[image]

How can I resolve this issue so the app doesnt crash because it's unable to read `segment: {segment: xxx}` I have tried a ternary operator within the filter. But that doesnt work :(

this is the main logic of my component

```js
  // CONSTRAINT CHECKBOXES
  const [constraintOptions, setConstraintOptions] = useState({
    constraints: [],
  })

  const duplicates = new Set()

  const duplicateObjects = mainData.filter(
    item => duplicates.size === duplicates.add(item.segment.segment).size,
  )

  const duplicateIds = new Set()

  const nextRoundFilteredObjects = duplicateObjects.filter(
    item =>
      duplicateIds.size !== duplicateIds.add(item.audience_id.audience_id).size,
  )

  // We return only the constraint values for the unique segment

  const unquieConstraints = [
    ...new Map(
      mainData
        .filter(row => row.segment === segment.segment)
        .map(item => [item.constraint_value, item]),
    ).values(),
  ]

  if (mainData.length === 0) {
    console.warn('WARNING: mainData is empty')
  } else {
    console.log('mainData', mainData)
  }

  function handleCheckBoxes(e) {
    const {value, checked} = e.target

    if (checked) {
      setConstraintOptions({
        constraints: [...constraintOptions.constraints, value],
      })
    } else {
      setConstraintOptions({
        constraints: constraintOptions.constraints.filter(e => e !== value),
      })
    }
  }

  function openSideBar() {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  function closeSideBar() {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  // Handles the error / success messages popup
  function popupValidation(type, message) {
    if (type === 'success') {
      setSuccess(true)
      setSuccessMessage(message)

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload()
      }, 2000)
    } else if (type === 'warning') {
      setWarning(true)
      setWarningMessage(message)

      setTimeout(() => {
        setError(false)
        window.location.reload()
      }, 2500)
    } else if (type === 'error') {
      setError(true)
      setErrorMessage(message)

      setTimeout(() => {
        setError(false)
        window.location.reload()
      }, 2500)
    }
  }

  async function getAudienceConstratints() {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
      .from('SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints')
      .select(
        `
        constraint_id,
        audience_id:SignalJourneyAudiences(audience_id),
        segment:SignalJourneyAudiences(segment) ,
        source:SignalJourneySources(source) ,
        constraint_type:SignalJourneyConstraintType(constraint_type),
        constraint_value,
        targeting,
        frequency,
        period
      `,
      )
      .order('constraint_id', {ascending: true})

    if (data) {
      setMainData(data)
    }
    if (error) {
      setErrorMessage('error', error.message)
    }
  }

  async function addNewRelationship() {
    closeSideBar()

    try {
      const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from('SignalJourneyAudienceConstraintRelations')
        .insert([
          {
            audience_id: segment.audience_id.audience_id,
            relation: relationship.condition,
            constraint_ids: constraintOptions.constraints.join('|'),
          },
        ])

      if (data) {
        popupValidation('success', 'Relationship added successfully')
      }
      if (error) {
        popupValidation('error', error.message)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }

    // RESET Relationships
    setSegment('')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAudienceConstratints()
  }, [])
```

### Update

This now works with the help from below

```js
const getAudienceConstratints = async () => {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
      .from('SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints')
      .select(
        `
        constraint_id,
        audience_id:SignalJourneyAudiences(audience_id),
        segment:SignalJourneyAudiences(segment) ,
        source:SignalJourneySources(source) ,
        constraint_type:SignalJourneyConstraintType(constraint_type),
        constraint_value,
        targeting,
        frequency,
        period
      `,
      )
      .order('constraint_id', {ascending: true})

    if (error) {
      setErrorMessage('error', error.message)
    }

    setMainData(data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
```

But I am having an issue with this...

```js
  const unquieConstraints = [
    ...new Map(
      mainData
        .filter(row => row.segment.segment === segment.segment.segment)
        .map(item => [item.constraint_value, item]),
    ).values(),
  ]
```

As `row.segment.segment` does not exist as is loaded before the return of the data.

Comment: Were is `mainData` defined?

Comment: `mainData` is defined by a state at the top of the component. Which is set by `getAudienceConstratints`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes perfect sense. Your component cannot know the value of something that needs to be fetched on mount.

The classic way to handle that kind of situation is using a state as follow:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState();
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getAudience().then((fetchedData) => { 
            setData(fetchedData);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }).catch((err) => {
            setError(err.toString());
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }, [])

    if (!!error) return <span>Error: {error}</span>;

    if (isLoading) return <span>Loading...</span>;

    // Here you do stuff on your data since you know it is ready

    return <span>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</span>;
}
```

You might consider creating a reusable hook to reduce code boilerplate. There are existing hooks created by the community for Supabase.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5nhteu9v/

Comment: this doesn't work because of the way async runs. I get what you're doing if it wasn't async

Comment: Why would it not work? https://jsfiddle.net/5nhteu9v/

Comment: for me i just keep getting an empty array

Comment: I just gave you an example that works with promises. You might need to check your async function to make sure it returns something. Also, don't do setState in your promise. Return the value and then do the setState in your useEffect hook.

Comment: I have found the issue, your fix works but now I am using a map which is populated before the return of the maindata. I need to figure out how to load that once the data is present, and still have access to the variable

Comment: Try doing your data treatment in your `.then`. Think of your state only as something made to pass mutable data to be displayed by your UI.

Comment: @mrpbennett, anytime you set a state (useState),  your component will rerender.  this is why async call should be fine if you are setting a state after data represented.

Comment: I have added what I am having issue with.

Comment: fixed it ....I had used `segment?.segment`

Comment: You can calculate unquieConstraints after the data has been initialised or (better), you should make it a function that takes data as an argument instead of using the state and you call it in your `.then`. You might consider reducing your example to a simpler scenario and open a new question.